# Mixing Fluid and Fixed Layout - Fill Dynamic Space

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, fluid-layout

I have recently Discovered that it is incredibly difficult to mix fluid and fixed layout, So when I finally figured out a solution to a problem Ive been having for quiet a while now, i couldn't resist but to share it with the community that has helped me so much in the past.

i wanted the following look:

[image: The Look i required]

by dynamic space i mean it should be very much like when one applies a "`margin:0 auto;`" CSS rule to a containing div, the white space left and right of the element is the "Dynamic Space" in the example.

I had 6 Requirements:

1. had to be responsive.
2. the container had to have a max width of 960px and always needed to be centered.
3. had to work on IE8 and up.
4. The Dynamic space on the left had to have a different height, and contain a different color.
5. The Dynamic Space on the right had to be the same height has the container but a different color.
6. Has to work with Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

At this point I struggled for 3 days, i tried everything from css table-cells to using bootstrap columns (neither worked out).

I also realized that the only way to have the div in the "same" position on huge screen sizes was to make it 50%.

So at this point i had the Following:

[**JSFIDDLE** DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/yW6hJ/5/)

which was pretty good, only problem was that the red stuck out underneath the container element.

So that My Wonderful Not At All Mathematical brain kicked in and thought:

if my containing element will always be 960px and i need my div on the left to be 50% to stay in the same position, what if i simply took 960/2 = 480px and simply applied `margin:-480px`.

which worked brilliantly.. until you scale your screen down to about 768px, so add a media query that changes it to `margin-left:-370px;`.

And it Finally Worked! Here's the Final Code:

[**JSFIDDLE** DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dawidvdh/yW6hJ/5/)

**AND HTML:**

```
<div class="" style="background: #000099; position: relative">
    <div class="left">l</div>
    <div class="container" style="background: #002500">contain</div>
</div>
```

**AND FINALLY CSS:**

```
.container {
    max-width: 960px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    padding:0;
}
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 50%;
    z-index: 1;
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    margin-left:-480px;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .left {
    margin-left:-375px; /*I Used -370 but for some reason it doesn't work now*/
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .left {
    margin-left:-480px;
  }
}
```

I Hope this Helps Someone, Sorry that its so long just wanted to explain the logic as clearly as possible.